.net 9 Maui CollectionView not showing data
I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022(64-bit) Version 17.12.3. I am also using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm. I have CasesPage.xaml, CasesPage.xaml.cs and CasesPageModel with ReportedCasesView.cs which is the Model file. I am trying to display a query result in a CollectionView but the data does not show up although the number of records retrieved is indicated. Below are the files and code I tried to achieve the results.
CasesPage.xaml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Bmcl.GhanaLawReport.Pages.CasesPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Bmcl.GhanaLawReport.Services"
             xmlns:pagemodel="clr-namespace:Bmcl.GhanaLawReport.PageModels"
             x:DataType="pagemodel:CasesPageModel"
             xmlns:sfradiobutton="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Maui.Buttons;assembly=Syncfusion.Maui.Buttons" 
             xmlns:inputLayout="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Maui.Core;assembly=Syncfusion.Maui.Core"
             xmlns:editors="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Maui.Inputs;assembly=Syncfusion.Maui.Inputs"
             xmlns:syncfusion="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Maui.ListView;assembly=Syncfusion.Maui.ListView"
             Title="Reported Cases">

    
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <pagemodel:CasesPageModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <Label Margin="10,0,10,0"
            Text="Ghana Law Reports"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="Title" />

            <Image Source="ghanacoatofarms.png" HeightRequest="50" Aspect="AspectFit" />

            <StackLayout Margin="5">
                <sfradiobutton:SfRadioGroup x:Name="CasesGroup">
                    
                    <sfradiobutton:SfRadioButton 
                        x:Name="ReportYear" 
                        Text="Case By Report Year" 
                        CheckedColor="Red" 
                        UncheckedColor="Black" 
                        StateChanged="ReportYear_StateChanged"/>
                    
                    <!--Setting ItemsSource-->
                    <editors:SfComboBox x:Name="LawReportComboBox"
                                    WidthRequest="250"
                                    HeightRequest = "50"
                                    IsEnabled="False"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="ReportName"
                                    TextMemberPath="ReportName"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding LawReportList}"
                                        SelectionChanged="LawReportComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>

                    <sfradiobutton:SfRadioButton
                        x:Name="AnyTextCaseTitle" 
                        Text="Case Title By Any Text" 
                        CheckedColor="Red" 
                        UncheckedColor="Black" 
                        StateChanged="AnyTextCaseTitle_StateChanged"/>

                    <Entry x:Name="CaseTitleEntry" 
                           IsEnabled="False" 
                           TextChanged="CaseTitleEntry_TextChanged"
                           Margin="30,0,10,0"/>
                   
                </sfradiobutton:SfRadioGroup>

            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Margin="10">
                <Button x:Name="Search" Text="Search"
                        BackgroundColor="Red"
                        TextColor="White"
                        Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"/>
            </StackLayout>
                    
            <VerticalStackLayout Margin="0,10,0,10">
                <Label Text="{Binding RecordsReturned}" 
                       TextColor="Red" FontSize="13" 
                       FontAttributes="Bold" 
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
                    
            <!--ListView Area-->
            <CollectionView x:Name="CasesCollectionView" 
                            SelectionMode="Single" 
                            EmptyView="No Data" 
                            ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding CaseTitlesList}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <VerticalStackLayout Padding="5" Margin="10" VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <Label Text="{Binding CaseName}" FontSize="Medium"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding CourtName}" FontSize="Small"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding ReportName}" FontSize="Small"/>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
                    
                    
                    
                    
        </VerticalStackLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>

CasesPage.xaml.cs file
using Bmcl.GhanaLawReport.Models;
using Bmcl.GhanaLawReport.PageModels;
using Bmcl.GhanaLawReport.Services;

namespace Bmcl.GhanaLawReport.Pages;

public partial class CasesPage : ContentPage
{
    public CasesPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ReportYear_StateChanged(object sender, Syncfusion.Maui.Buttons.StateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.IsChecked.HasValue && e.IsChecked.Value)
        {
            AppProperties.ReportedCasesSearchOption = 1;
            LawReportComboBox.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            LawReportComboBox.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void AnyTextCaseTitle_StateChanged(object sender, Syncfusion.Maui.Buttons.StateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.IsChecked.HasValue && e.IsChecked.Value)
        { 
            AppProperties.ReportedCasesSearchOption = 2;
            CaseTitleEntry.IsEnabled = true; 
        }
        else
        { 
            CaseTitleEntry.IsEnabled = false; 
        }
    }

    private void CaseTitleEntry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        AppProperties.ReportedCasesAnyTextParameter = CaseTitleEntry.Text;
    }

    private void LawReportComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, Syncfusion.Maui.Inputs.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        AppProperties.LawReportComboParameter = LawReportComboBox.Text;
    }

}

CasesPageModel.cs file (ViewModel if you like)
using Bmcl.GhanaLawReport.Models;
using Bmcl.GhanaLawReport.Services;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Bmcl.GhanaLawReport.PageModels
{
    public partial class CasesPageModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private Int32 totalRecords = 0;

        [ObservableProperty]
        string recordsReturned = "";

        [ObservableProperty]
        ObservableCollection<ReportedCasesView> caseTitlesList = [];

        [ObservableProperty]
        ObservableCollection<LawReportIndexView> lawReportList = [];

        [ObservableProperty]
        int indexId = 0;

        [ObservableProperty]
        int caseId = 0;

        [ObservableProperty]
        int courtId = 0;

        [ObservableProperty]
        int reportId = 0;

        [ObservableProperty]
        string? caseName;

        [ObservableProperty]
        string? courtName;

        [ObservableProperty]
        string? reportName;

        [ObservableProperty]
        string? judges;

        public CasesPageModel()
        {
            GetLawReports();
        }

        private void GetLawReports()
        {
            var lawReports = Data.LawReport.ReadAllLawReports.Read();
            if (lawReports != null)
                LawReportList = new ObservableCollection<LawReportIndexView>(lawReports);
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public async Task Search()
        {
            await GetSerchOptions();
        }

        private async Task GetSerchOptions()
        {
            switch(AppProperties.ReportedCasesSearchOption)
            {
                case 1:
                    if(AppProperties.LawReportComboParameter == string.Empty || 
                        AppProperties.LawReportComboParameter == null)
                    {
                        //--Message here
                        if(Application.Current?.Windows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            var page = Application.Current.Windows[0].Page;
                            if(page != null)
                            {
                                await page.DisplayAlert("Reported Case Error",
                                    "Please select a Law Report ", "OK");
                            }
                        }
                        return;
                    }

                    var caseTitles = await Data.ReportedCase.ReadCaseTitleByReport.ReadAsync(AppProperties.LawReportComboParameter);

                    if (caseTitles != null)
                    {
                        CaseTitlesList = new ObservableCollection<ReportedCasesView>(caseTitles);
                        totalRecords = caseTitles.Count;
                        RecordsReturned = $"Showing {totalRecords} Returned Records";
                    }

                    break;
                case 2:
                    if(AppProperties.ReportedCasesAnyTextParameter == string.Empty || 
                        AppProperties.ReportedCasesAnyTextParameter == null)
                    {
                        //--Message here
                        if(Application.Current?.Windows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            var page = Application.Current.Windows[0].Page;
                            if(page != null)
                            {
                                await page.DisplayAlert("Reported Case Error",
                                    "Please supply a Case Title ", "OK");
                            }
                        }
                        return;
                    }

                    var cases = await Data.ReportedCase.ReadCaseTitleByAnyText.ReadAsync(AppProperties.ReportedCasesAnyTextParameter);

                    if (cases != null)
                    {
                        CaseTitlesList = new ObservableCollection<ReportedCasesView>(cases);
                        totalRecords = cases.Count;
                        RecordsReturned = $"Showing {totalRecords} Returned Records";
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}


ReportedCasesView (Model file)
namespace Bmcl.GhanaLawReport.Models
{
    public class ReportedCasesView
    {
        public int IndexId { get; set; }
        public int CaseId { get; set; }
        public int CourtId { get; set; }
        public int ReportId { get; set; }
        public string? CaseName { get; set; }
        public string? CourtName { get; set; }
        public string? ReportName { get; set; }
        public string? Judges { get; set; }
    }
}


What I want to achieve is very simple. For the queried data's result to be displayed the CollectionView.
Thank you in advance for your help.

try specifying a Height value for the collection.  You have it nested within a StackLayout and a ScrollView, it probably cannot determine what the correct layout height should be

Thank you Jason. I have tried the Height but it's still the same. Nothing shows up. I have even tried moving some of the containers but it will still not show up. But I want this thing to work.

@Bainn are you sure that all the items in CaseTitlesList contains data?

Hi Bhavanesh, I stepped into the code to make sure the sql server query is returning the correct number of records as is in the database. Also the number of records returned is shown.

To resolve your data from not appearing in the CollectionView a few small changes need to be made.
In CasesPage.xaml we will define a model to the DataTemplate element:
<!--...omitting previous xaml code for brevity -->
<CollectionView x:Name="CasesCollectionView" 
                SelectionMode="Single" 
                EmptyView="No Data" 
                ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid"
                ItemsSource="{Binding CaseTitlesList}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <!-- Replace <DataTemplate> with: -->
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:ReportedCasesView"> 
            <VerticalStackLayout Padding="5" Margin="10" VerticalOptions="Center" >
                <Label Text="{Binding CaseName}" FontSize="Medium"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding CourtName}" FontSize="Small"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding ReportName}" FontSize="Small"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>

CasesPageModel.cs:
// Replace
//[ObservableProperty]
//ObservableCollection<ReportedCasesView> caseTitlesList = [];

// With This:
// Make the property visible to the xaml page and 
// avoids accessibility errors from auto generated code
public ObservableCollection<ReportedCasesView> CaseTitlesList { get; private set; } = [];

CasesPageModel.cs data retrieval changes - make this same change in the other switch case:
[RelayCommand]
public async Task Search()
{
    // Clear previous collection on new search
    CaseTitlesList.Clear();
    await GetSearchOptions(); // Fixed typo on this method
}

// ... omitting error checking and switch statement for brevity

var caseTitles = await Data.ReportedCase.ReadCaseTitleByReport.ReadAsync(AppProperties.LawReportComboParameter);

if (caseTitles is not null)
{
    // Reinitializing the Collection won't update the UI
    // CaseTitlesList = new ObservableCollection<ReportedCasesView>(cases);
    
    // Since the collection was cleared, we add the results of the new search
    // we can load these incrementally as well, see related links
    foreach (var item in caseTitles)
    {
        CaseTitlesList.Add(item);
    }
    totalRecords = CaseTitlesList.Count;
    RecordsReturned = $"Showing {totalRecords} Returned Records";
}
break;
// consider adding a default: break; at the end of the switch statement

I was able to successfully test this solution using sample JSON data and simulated query. Hope this helps!
Supporting / Related Links:
Stack Overflow Similar/Related Question
CollectionView MS Docs - See Sample Code
CollectionView Incremental Loading

In short, make the collection a property and append elements instead of replace the collection. Lots of GPT spam for so little. Also, you don't make the collection have a setter, public or private. It screams not understanding C#.

@Blindy I'm new to answering questions, just trying to be thorough to avoid confusion. There's no "GPT spam" believe it or not I don't care, maybe give some pointers on answering better instead of screaming rude comments.

Good morning everyone and most importantly to a beautiful morning to Wiseotter. There is no need for argument here. This question has been here for about a week or so and I nearly gave up to switch to .net 8. Just to check for the last time before switching to .net8, here Wiseotter answer was the solution. It worked like magic and I am very grateful. I may place myself between beginner and advance and Wiseotter's thoroughness has helped me greatly. Not everybody is an advance programmer, bear that one in mind. Thank you very much indeed, Wiseotter. Thank you Stackoverflow.
